# iOS make view smartly follow another view

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have the following problem:
I have one UIImageView which I can drag by touch and a toolbar, which I want to be near that Image View. This is, what I'm doing at the moment:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  //motion here;self.tool is toolbar View

  CGFloat a=self.tool.frame.size.width;
  CGFloat b=self.tool.frame.size.height;
  self.tool.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x+self.frame.size.width/2+50, self.frame.origin.y+self.frame.size.height/2+50, a, b);
}
```

It works fine but sometimes toolbar is moving outside of screen. Maybe there is simple way to track if I am outside and move toolbar to another point?

Comment: Check the bounds of the object you are moving with the screen's frame. And stop further movement once it hits the borders of the screen. Isn't this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it like this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  //motion here;self.tool is toolbar View

  CGFloat a = self.tool.frame.size.width;
  CGFloat b = self.tool.frame.size.height;
  CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x+self.frame.size.width/2+50, 
                               self.frame.origin.y+self.frame.size.height/2+50,
                               a, b);

  // only set frame, if it is still in the bounds of self.superview
  if(CGRectContainsRect(self.superview.frame, newFrame)) {
    self.tool.frame = newFrame;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using UIGestureRecognizer, not touchesMoved:. And when you do, the gesture recognizer on the image view can move the toolbar view however it likes.